# Clasificar variable cualitativa por número de deciles

Tags: r, funciones

¿Existe una forma de realizar lo siguiente?:

Tengo un conjunto de datos cuantitativos, y deseo crear una categoría dependiendo el decil en el que se encuentre el número, pero esta categoría depende del número de deciles que se incluyan en el código, es decir, si deseo que particione los datos en 3 deciles, la función debe sacar las categorías 1 y 2, si ingreso 4 deciles, clasificar en categoría 1, 2 y 3 y así sucesivamente.

Anexo ejemplo de lo que aspiro obtener, al cambiar el parámetro "length":

```
set.seed(2020)
df<-rnorm(100,3,4)
df1<-data.frame(datos=df)
```

###Ejemplo 1

```
df2<-quantile(df, prob=seq(0, 1, length = 3))
df1$categoria<-ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[2]],1,2)
```

###Ejemplo 2

```
df2<-quantile(df, prob=seq(0, 1, length = 4))
df1$categoria<-ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[2]],1,
ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[3]],2,3))
```

###Ejemplo 3

```
df2<-quantile(df, prob=seq(0, 1, length = 5))
df1$categoria<-ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[2]],1,
ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[3]],2,
ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[4]],3,4)))
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, lo que deseas calcular son percentiles y no deciles, los deciles sólo dividen a los datos en 10 partes "iguales".

La función `ifelse()` sirve más si se usa cuando quieres clasificar a través de elementos `caracter`. Pero si deseas clasificar por elementos `numéricos` lo mejor es usar la función `cut()`.

Aquí te muestro una solución a la cuestión que atraviesas.

```
percentiles<-function(x,len){
  a<-quantile(x, prob=seq(0, 1, length = len))
  b<-as.numeric(cut(x, breaks = a, labels = seq(len-1), right = F, include.lowest=T))
  b
}
```

Vamos a probarlo para el caso que quieras categorizarlos por cuartiles.

```
percentiles(df1$datos, len = 5)

  [1] 3 3 1 1 1 3 4 2 4 2 1 4 4 2 2 4 4 1 1 2 4 4 3 2 4 3 4 4 2 2 1 1 4 4 3 3 2 2 2 3 4 2 2 1 1 3 2
 [48] 2 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 1 1 3 4 3 1 4 4 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 2 4 3 1 4 1 4 4 3 1 1 3 4
 [95] 2 1 3 3 2 1
```

En efecto, salen los mismos resultados que obtendrías si usas:

```
df2<-quantile(df, prob=seq(0, 1, length = 5))
df1$categoria<-ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[2]],1,
ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[3]],2,
ifelse(df1$datos<df2[[4]],3,4)))
```

Espero haya podido ayudarte.